# ArrayList Remove Isn't Removing Object

Tags: java, arraylist

I have two ArrayLists, a hand of Cards and then a "run" of Cards (Cards are objects.) I am trying to initiate through the "run" of Cards, and remove those specific cards from the Hand.

I have the exact same code in a different method and it works fantastic. For some reason, the code below isn't removing any of the "run" cards from Hand, and I can't figure out why. The debugger shows the method passing the right Card; any ideas?

```
private ArrayList<ArrayList<Card>> meldDesktop;     

public void addMeldRun(ArrayList runToAdd, Hand playerHand, Player player){

    this.meldDesktop.add(runToAdd);

    //after adding the run to the meld desktop, remove them from the player's
    //hand and get points
    Iterator<Card> testRoll = runToAdd.iterator();
    while (testRoll.hasNext()){
        int points = 0;
        Card removeCard = testRoll.next();
        playerHand.removeCard(removeCard);
        points = removeCard.pointValue() + points;
        player.setScore(points);

    }
}

 public ArrayList removeCard (Card newCard){
    handCard.remove(newCard);
    //Collections.sort(handCard);
    return handCard;
}
```

Comment: Check the return value of `handCard.remove(newCard)` to see if it successfully removed the card.

Comment: It does not. handCard.remove(newCard) shows the arrayList.size at 7, and then return handCard also displays a return size of 7. So the removeCard seems to be getting the right Card, but stuck somewhere there in the middle.

Comment: What is handCard?  You haven't shown where/how that's declared.  Are you sure that the object's reference being returned `runToAdd.next()` is actually the same reference (not necessarily the same data) stored in `handCard`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Likely the issues is the card objects are being copyed/cloned some how thus they are not the same object as the ones that are in the playerHand object. Thus they are not passing the equals check in handCard.remove(newCard);

You can test this with:

```
boolean removed = handCard.remove(newCard);
System.out.println(newCard.pointValue() + " removed = " + removed);
```

Most likely this issues is in how you add cards to the runToAdd object.

Also you could improve you while loop or even better use an enhanced for loop:

```
int points = 0;
for (Card removeCard : testRoll){
    playerHand.removeCard(removeCard);
    points += removeCard.pointValue();
}
player.setScore(points);
```

Let me know the result of the test and I will update the answer with what you should look at next.

Comment: Ah you're brilliant! Way else in my code, I was creating a new Card and adding *that* to the runToAdd ArrayList, instead of the Card in the Hand arrayList. Thank you so much!

Comment: NP, glad I could help. ;)

Answer (score 2):

You have not provided enough information for a proper diagnosis / explanation for your particular problem.

However, there is only one plausible explanation for `List.remove(elem)` not working.  That is that `elem` is not "in" the list ... according to the defined semantics of "in" as per the javadocs.

Breaking that down:

- It could simply be that the element isn't in the list ... in any sense.
- It could also be that the element isn't in the list because the implementation of the `equals(Object)` method is not correct for the "in the list" semantic you are expecting.

The specification for `remove` in the `List` API is that it uses the `equals(Object)` method.  If `elem.equals(obj)` is `true` for some `obj` that is in the list, then that object will be removed.

But here's the rub.  The default implementation of `equals(Object)` that is inherited from `java.lang.Object` is to simply compare object references.  If you don't override `equals(Object)` for your `Card` class AND your application creates multiple instances of (say) "The King of Clubs" ... then `remove` is liable to fail because you tried to remove the wrong one.

---

The other way to address this is to use the debugger to single step through the `remove` method (observing the local variables, etcetera) to see what is actually happening.  In particular, look for the point where it *should* be matching the element (`Card`) you want to remove.

However, I expect that will just confirm what I said above.

---

The take away is that you code needs to do one of the following:

- make sure that "The King of Clubs" is only ever created once; i.e. never copy it, never clone it, never `new` another instance, etc, OR
- override `equals(Object)` to compare `Card` objects by value; i.e. so that all instances of "The King of Clubs" are treated as equal.  Obviously, the semantics will depend on the rules of the game you are simulating ... but you need to think that through for yourself.

Comment: This is a fantastic point that I wish I learned when I first started programming..  Your overriding implementation of `equals()` in java is critical if you don't want reference comparisons all the time.